# Works in Netbeans, but not "outside" of it

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

This code works perfect when I press *PLAY* in netbeans, but when I build it and start the Jar file it will not.

```
private void SettingsMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
ImageIcon Setting = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pic/settings-icon.png"));
Settings.setIcon(Setting);
     HooverBar.setText("Settings");
}                                     

private void SettingsMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
ImageIcon Setting = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pic/settings-icon-half.png"));
Settings.setIcon(Setting);
     HooverBar.setText("");
}                                    

private void SettingsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
card.show(mainPanel,"gui5"); 
}
```

I can not figure out what I have done?

When i start the with "Java -jar Knowhow.jar" and move the mouse over the "settings" i get this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at AppPackage.GUI.SettingsMouseEntered(GUI.java:1755)
    at AppPackage.GUI.access$1200(GUI.java:26)
    at AppPackage.GUI$11.mouseEntered(GUI.java:278)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are the `png` files included within the resulting jar?

Comment: What result do you get? How do you "build and start" the .jar file?

Comment: Try to keep up with the conventions and name your variables with a starting lowercase letter.  `Setting` is normally the name of a class while `setting` is the name of a variable instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are not packaged within your jar. You need to change that.

I can't tell from the details of your question why that happens but the context is this:

```
getClass().getResource("/pic/settings-icon.png")
```

is loading the image from your classpath. That is from each element of the classpath. So your NetBeans classpath is different from the one of your `java -jar` command.

Have a look at the run configuration in your NetBeans to see your classpath there and map the classpath of your command to it.

Comment: Thx, i just moved the pic to the main folder